# domai name availbility checker

Tags: php, jquery, dns

actually i am looking for jquery and php script for checking domain name availability and whois.

like this example

http://davidwalsh.name/?s=WHOIS%20Domain%20Availability%20Checker

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [phpwhois](http://www.phpwhois.com/) for getting whois data.  It doesn't do it the ajax way, so you will have to write a simple page to make an ajax call as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used those, but maybe the PEAR packages [`Net_Whois`](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.networking.net-whois.query.php) and/or [`Net_DNS`](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_DNS/docs) could be helpful ?